# Android: systemNavigationBarIconBrightness reverts itself to light after app restore

Tags: android, flutter, themes, navbar

Minimal sample app to reproduce problem:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  var overlayStyle = SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    statusBarBrightness: Platform.isAndroid ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
    systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.white,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  );

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(overlayStyle);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

To reproduce:

- run app. System navbar is white with dark nav buttons
- display all recent apps or show desktop on your device
- run app again (or choose it again from latest apps list)

You will get system navbar white with nav buttons set to light (not visible on white navbar). For me, it looks like a Flutter bug. Do you have any idea or workaround?

Comment: Have you found a workaround? I experience the same problem with my app :(